# Debugging an Android application connected to the localhost mysql database server using actual device

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm new to Android development. I have developed a simple Android application that communicates with the localhost mysql database server.

Using PHP scripts I'm trying to communicate. The scripts are in my **htdoc** directory, which was created by **xammp**. I'm trying to connect to the db from my Android application using the URL:

```
"192.168.X.X"
```

[snippet for the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgUAT.png)
I'm using the static IP of my PC for this.

With this, my application is working well in the emulator, but when I start debugging it with an actual device, nothing happens. I get error saying fail to connect. I need help with this.

Thanks in advance!

[LogCat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUEQk.png)

`03-17 14:02:37.337 27521-27521/com.example.anonymous.chefy W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
03-17 14:02:37.337 27521-27521/com.example.anonymous.chefy W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17966: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
03-17 14:02:37.347 27521-27521/com.example.anonymous.chefy W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17970: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
03-17 14:02:37.397 27521-27521/com.example.anonymous.chefy W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 422: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
03-17 14:02:37.397 27521-27521/com.example.anonymous.chefy W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 444: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
03-17 14:02:37.427 27521-27521/com.example.anonymous.chefy W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 385: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-17 14:02:37.427 27521-27521/com.example.anonymous.chefy W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 387: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-17 14:02:37.567 27521-27521/com.example.anonymous.chefy I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: TERESAH_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.7.2_RB1.04.04.04.156.011+PATCH[ES]_msm8916_32_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.7.2_RB1.04.04.04.156.011__release_ENGG ()
                                                                         OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.02.07
                                                                         Build Date: 09/16/14 Tue
                                                                         Local Branch: 
                                                                         Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.7.2_RB1.04.04.04.156.011
                                                                         Local Patches: 7f57dafbc79add1324a1545ea5f0189a573f2039 es20: Fix conformance ES3-CTS.gtf.GL.read_format.read_format failure
                                                                                          b28b4bb91f74a0e43ee701
03-17 14:02:37.747 27521-27521/com.example.anonymous.chefy I/InputMethodManager: [startInputInner] EditorInfo { packageName=com.example.anonymous.chefy, inputType=0x61, imeOptions=0x8004005, privateImeOptions=null }, windowGainingFocus=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@41ba3378, mServedView=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{41b7b638 VFED..CL .F....I. 150,102-570,193 #7f0c006d app:id/editText}
03-17 14:02:39.157 27521-27521/com.example.anonymous.chefy W/Editor: GetLabel fail! Do framework orig behavior
03-17 14:02:43.027 27521-27521/com.example.anonymous.chefy I/InputMethodManager: [startInputInner] EditorInfo { packageName=com.example.anonymous.chefy, inputType=0x1, imeOptions=0xc004005, privateImeOptions=null }, windowGainingFocus=null, mServedView=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{41b84ad8 VFED..CL .F.P..ID 150,257-570,348 #7f0c006e app:id/editText2}
03-17 14:02:43.037 27521-27521/com.example.anonymous.chefy W/Editor: GetLabel fail! Do framework orig behavior
03-17 14:02:49.977 27521-27521/com.example.anonymous.chefy I/InputMethodManager: [startInputInner] EditorInfo { packageName=com.example.anonymous.chefy, inputType=0x81, imeOptions=0x4001006, privateImeOptions=null }, windowGainingFocus=null, mServedView=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{41b86a38 VFED..CL .F.P..ID 150,348-560,439 #7f0c006f app:id/editText3}
03-17 14:02:49.997 27521-27521/com.example.anonymous.chefy W/Editor: GetLabel fail! Do framework orig behavior
03-17 14:02:53.067 27521-28268/com.example.anonymous.chefy D/myTag: aa
03-17 14:02:53.187 27521-28268/com.example.anonymous.chefy D/libc: [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 13(0x3139322e313638),sn(),family 0,flags 4
03-17 14:02:53.187 27521-28268/com.example.anonymous.chefy D/libc: [NET] getaddrinfo-, SUCCESS
03-17 14:02:53.187 27521-28268/com.example.anonymous.chefy D/libc: [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 13(0x3139322e313638),sn(),family 0,flags 4
03-17 14:02:53.187 27521-28268/com.example.anonymous.chefy D/libc: [NET] getaddrinfo-, SUCCESS
03-17 14:03:05.597 27521-27521/com.example.anonymous.chefy I/InputMethodManager: [startInputInner] EditorInfo { packageName=com.example.anonymous.chefy, inputType=0x61, imeOptions=0x8004005, privateImeOptions=null }, windowGainingFocus=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@41c97948, mServedView=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{41c8bd68 VFED..CL .F....I. 150,102-570,193 #7f0c006d app:id/editText}
03-17 14:03:32.117 27521-27521/com.example.anonymous.chefy W/IInputConnectionWrapper: reportFullscreenMode on inactive InputConnection
03-17 14:03:32.267 27521-27521/com.example.anonymous.chefy D/HardwareRenderer: startTrimMemory(level >=TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE)`

Comment: @Razgriz i added the logCat

Comment: uh no. don't link an imgur screencap of your logcat. copy paste the logcat here

Comment: @Razgriz here it says its too long to comment :/

Comment: *copy paste the logcat in your original post and NOT post it in the comments.